# How to use controls value in mysql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have a database with the tables and columns:
persons: id, first_name, last_name
addresses: id, city, street_number, persons_id

I'm trying to make a search engine in asp.net. 
I have controls: TextBox1, DropDownList1, Button1, GridView1 with SqlDataSource1.
The DropDownList1 code:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    DataValueField="first_name" AutoPostBack="false">
    <asp:ListItem Value="first_name">First name</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="last_name">Last name</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="city">City</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the SqlDataSource control: in the SelectCommand I'm trying to make something like this:

```
       SelectCommand="SELECT first_name, last_name, city FROM persons, addresses WHERE persons.id = addresses.persons_id AND (? LIKE '%'??'%')">
```

In the ? and ?? I want to put the values from DropDownList1 and TextBox1. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need two `asp:ControlParameter`'s in your `SqlDataSource1` like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="YourConnectionString"
    SelectCommand="SELECT first_name, last_name, city FROM persons, addresses WHERE persons.id = addresses.persons_id AND (@FirstLastCity LIKE '%@SearchString%')">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="FirstLastCity" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="SearchString" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This should be the first step. I am pretty sure that `'%@SearchString%'` in the `SelectCommand` will not work. But there must be a way to concatinate `%`, `@SearchString` and `%` in the markup code.
Alternatively you can set parameter values in code behind like this:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@SearchString", "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%");
```

Comment: Did you try to debug and catch the select query string of the datasource before it executes the query on the database server? Does it work when you replace `'%@SearchString%'` by just `@SearchString` and search for exact values? PS: I modified the answer a bit.

Comment: The first solution didn't work, for the code behind you mean. Should I open a MySqlConnection in the Button1_Click event?

Comment: No, please use the `Selecting` event of your `SqlDataSource` and have a look at the event argument. Which values do you get there for the two parameters `e.Command.Parameters[0].Value` and `e.Command.Parameters[1].Value`?